# Deep diving into android resource internals

Tags: android, android-layout

Recently, as I was going through the android behavioural updation after multi-window things started seeming weird. The callbacks of onConfigurationChanged don't seem to occur when we just resize the application.

This accounts for an hypothesis that the android might just fetch it's resources (i.e. dimens or others) based on physical screen size and not based on device configuration (as this was not changed in this scenario).
As a part of curiosity, I was keenly looking for how android internally happens to decide whether on dimens to used should be from dimens or land/dimens.

I would appreciate if someone can post any concrete base of how this relates to usual and multi-window case.

Comment: it will not use `landscape`, the rest should be the same.

Comment: This is from Documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#BestMatch

Comment: I would prefer something more from the internals. Which means something as in what triggers the application/system to find a new view/layout in terms of the state.

This means even after having an idea about how the priority of having resources explains itself, I was curious to understand how this will be applied for multiwindow scenario.
Because the case is that, the orientation change callbacks are not received if it is not mentioned in the Manifest ("smallestScreenWidth"). And ironically even if I don't mention that, android still manages to handle that.
I was keen to understand how!